# Finding the category id's on category intersection pages

Tags: categories, multi-taxonomy-query

I'm using category intersection pages for users to be able to filter posts by categories.

E.g. http://freemapsalgarve.com/category/destinations/alvor+bars-pubs/

Here the user is filtering on the "alvor" AND "bars-pubs" child categories of "destinations".

I want to be able to get the id's of the categories that are being filtered on the page so I can display them to the user but I am only able to get the first category.

`$this_cat = get_category(get_query_var('cat'));`

...returns the first category "alvor" in this example.

Does anyone know how I could find the both categories being filtered on here?

Comment: What are _"category intersection pages"_? This is no default WordPress vocabulary. Please elaborate.

Comment: In WordPress you can display the intersection or union of two taxonomies using the + or , operators in the url: E.g. /categories/a+b - would show all posts in category A AND B. Some more info here - http://ryan.boren.me/2007/10/01/taxonomy-intersections-and-unions/

Comment: Oh, you're simply talking about a `tax_query`. Why didn't you say that. Ryan Boran uses a wired vocabulary for a core dev. Oh and this post is from WP version 2.3. Things are quite different these days. `set_query_var()` for example was replaced using `$query->set()`, etc. Just `var_dump( $GLOBALS['wp_query'] );` and post a link to a pastebin (or similar) here.

Comment: Here's the output of var_dump: http://pastebin.com/DxyMPYxq - I can see that there are two category_name fields - one containing both category names and one containing only a single category name.

Comment: David, could you please wrap this inside `<pre>` tags. This is not readable.

Comment: Done, sorry - http://pastebin.com/PhbWFkLs

Answer (score 1):

If you're in the loop, simply use [`get_categories()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories).

Comment: This just lists out all the categories in the system - I want to know the names of the Categories being displayed on the Category intersection page being viewed - outside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

If you're **not in the loop** and want to get the queried terms, then there's *no* native API function as well as *no* `WP_Query` or `WP_Tax_Query` object method available (like for example `get_queried_object()`). You'll have to access it directly.

Example of what the `tax_query` looks like (provided by the OP):

```
["tax_query"]=>
  object(WP_Tax_Query)#282 (2) {
    ["queries"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(5) {
        ["taxonomy"]=>
        string(8) "category"
        ["terms"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(5) "alvor"
        }
        ["include_children"]=>
        bool(true)
        ["field"]=>
        string(4) "slug"
        ["operator"]=>
        string(2) "IN"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(5) {
        ["taxonomy"]=>
        string(8) "category"
```

Now we need to access that `$wp_query` object. We'll do that with a small plugin that will output the necessary parts.

```
<?php
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) or exit;
/* Plugin Name: (#90230) Get Taxonomy terms */
add_filter( 'parse_query', 'wpse90230_parse_query' );
function wpse90230_parse_query( $wp_query )
{
    // This is the tax_query/WP_Tax_Query object
    $tax_query = $wp_query->tax_query; 

    // Now we get the relation `AND`/`OR` so we have a possibilty to the tell the user
    // whether we are showing them a "match" or a "filtered" result
    $relation = 'AND' === $tax_query->relation ? "filtered" : "matched";

    // Then we're extracting the terms.
    // This gives us the terms as array sorted by taxonomy.
    foreach ( $tax_query->queries as $tax_query )
        $terms[ $tax_query["taxonomy"] ] = $tax_query["terms"];

    // Now we can loop through them:
    printf( 'You are viewing %s', get_post_type() );
    foreach ( $terms as $taxonomy => $terms )
        printf(
             '%s: %s'
            ,get_taxonomy( $taxonomy )->label
            ,join( ",", $terms )
        );
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kaiser - trying out your example at the top of my category page (below the header but before the loop) gives the following output: "You are viewing postCategories: bars-pubs" - it doesn't seem to be seeing the other category "Alvor" which should be there since the path is /category/destinations/alvor+bars-pubs/

Comment: @David Please do a `var_dump( $terms )` before the `foreach()` loop.

Comment: Here's the output: `array(1) { ["category"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(9) "bars-pubs" } }` from this page - http://freemapsalgarve.com/category/destinations/alvor+bars-pubs/

Comment: In this case you seem to do several queries. And this query _only_ holds the `bars-pubs` term... Seems like you're interfering earlier. I'll write an update. You can then use it and inspect the output.